# How to compare Object Arrays using Arrays.equals() in java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

in this example showing how to do it :

```
Student[] stud1 = new Student[2];
Student[] stud2 = new Student[2];
Student[] stud3 = new Student[2];
boolean b;
stud1[0]= new Student("Johnny","Bravo");
stud1[1]= new Student("Ace","Ventura");
stud2[0]= new Student("Ash","Ketchum");
stud2[1]= new Student("Mike","Wazowski");
b = Arrays.equals(stud1,stud2);
System.out.println(b);
stud2 [0] = stud1[0];
stud2[1] = stud1[1];
b = Arrays.equals(stud1,stud2);
System.out.println(b); 
stud3 = stud1;
b = Arrays.equals(stud1,stud3);
System.out.println(b);
}
```

the result is **false true true**. What is Arrays.equals comparing exactly?
thanks.

Comment: *What is Arrays.equals comparing exactly?* It's checking equality between elements, as defined by `Object.equals()`. Are you surprised by something specific?

Comment: The elements here are objects; is it comparing the references stud1[0] with stud2[0] and stud2[0] with stud2[1] or comparing what's inside ("Johnny","Bravo" with "Ash","Ketchum"....)

Comment: It's using `Object.equals()`. If you've overridden that method, it will use your implementation. Otherwise it's checking identity, or reference equality.

Answer (score 4):

Directly from [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-):

> Returns `true` if the two specified arrays of `Objects` are equal to one another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. Two objects `e1` and `e2` are considered equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`. In other words, the two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are `null`.

That pretty much explains everything. In your case, the first output is `false` because `stud1` and `stud2` have instances of `Student` that are not equal. In the second case, the two arrays have identical objects, and hence test as equal. In the third case, `stud1` and `stud3` are the same object, hence also equal.

The only interesting case would be if `Student` had an `equals()` method and you wanted to test two arrays that had equivalent but not identical `Student` objects:

```
Student[] stud1 = {
    new Student("Johnny","Bravo")
};
Student[] stud2 = {
    new Student("Johnny","Bravo")
};
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(stud1, stud2));
```

Here the output would depend on the implementation of `Student.equals()`.

Comment: Also, as a sidenote: remember to override `equals` on `Student` class. In your code snippet it wouldn't make a difference, but in general it's important for `Array.equals` to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`array1.equals(array2)` is the same as `array1 == array2`, i.e. is it the same array.

`Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` compares the contents of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

According to javadoc of equals method of Arrays class:

> Returns true if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one another.  The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal.  Two objects e1 and e2 are considered equal if
>
> ```
>   (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).
> ```
>
> In other words, the two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.  Also, two array references are considered equal if both are null.

Here elements in the array are "java.lang.String" so you should also look into Strings equal method, which says,

> Compares this string to the specified object.  The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Comment: All that bold text makes your answer hard to read.  Consider using the blockquote markup instead, by starting a paragraph with `>`.

Comment: The elements of OP's arrays are instances of `Student`, not instances of `String`.

Comment: Thanks @VGR for the tip.